# Centos 6 - Postfix wont send to own domain without flag

Tags: centos, postfix, sendmail

I am moving a site to another server and am having an issue with PHP mail. But only when sending mail to the host domain e.g anything@example.com.

```
mail($send_to, 'Web contact' ,$message,null,"-r support@example.com");
```

The only way I can get mail to send is by adding the -r flag it doesn't seem to matter what e-mail address is entered after the flag.

This is a migration from Centos 5 to 6 and I believe mail is now using Postfix as opposed to sendMail.

Is there a Postfix setting that I can change to stop having to add this flag to every call of the mail function?

Additionally is there a way to force the use of sendMail instead of using Postfix if I can't fix this?

I should have mentioned I know that the mail is been routed internally as is shown from the log:

EDIT

This is failed attempt without flag

```
May 14 16:13:12 test sendmail[10244]: t4EFDCLq010244: from=apache, size=169, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201505141513.t4EFDCLq010244@example.com>, relay=apache@localhost
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: 9EFB3256738: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/cleanup[10248]: 9EFB3256738: message-id=<201505141513.t4EFDCLq010244@example.com>
May 14 16:13:12 test sendmail[10244]: t4EFDCLq010244: to=support@example.com, ctladdr=apache (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30169, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 9EFB3256738)
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: 9EFB3256738: from=<apache@example.com>, size=592, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/smtp[10249]: 9EFB3256738: to=<support@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[748.31.105.444]:25, delay=0.1, delays=0.04/0.01/0.01/0.03, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.example.com[748.31.105.444] said: 550-Verification failed for <apache@example.com> 550-No Such User Here" 550 Sender verify failed (in reply to RCPT TO command))
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/cleanup[10248]: B47B625675D: message-id=<20150514151312.B47B625675D@example.com>
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/bounce[10250]: 9EFB3256738: sender non-delivery notification: B47B625675D
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: B47B625675D: from=<>, size=2524, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: 9EFB3256738: removed
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/smtp[10249]: B47B625675D: to=<apache@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[748.31.105.444]:25, delay=0.03, delays=0/0/0.01/0.02, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mail.example.com[748.31.105.444] said: 550 No Such User Here" (in reply to RCPT TO command))
May 14 16:13:12 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: B47B625675D: removed
```

And this is with the flag

```
May 14 16:13:23 test sendmail[10251]: t4EFDN45010251: Authentication-Warning: example.com: apache set sender to test@example.com using -r
May 14 16:13:23 test sendmail[10251]: t4EFDN45010251: from=test@example.com, size=169, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201505141513.t4EFDN45010251@example.com>, relay=apache@localhost
May 14 16:13:23 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:23 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: 3B3EF256738: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:23 test postfix/cleanup[10248]: 3B3EF256738: message-id=<201505141513.t4EFDN45010251@example.com>
May 14 16:13:23 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: 3B3EF256738: from=<test@example.com>, size=662, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
May 14 16:13:23 test sendmail[10251]: t4EFDN45010251: to=support@example.com, ctladdr=test@example.com (48/48), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30169, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok: queued as 3B3EF256738)
May 14 16:13:23 test postfix/smtpd[10245]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
May 14 16:13:24 test postfix/smtp[10249]: 3B3EF256738: to=<support@example.com>, relay=mail.example.com[748.31.105.444]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.03/0/0.01/1.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 OK id=1Ysup9-0001Rr-Jv)
May 14 16:13:24 test postfix/qmgr[10102]: 3B3EF256738: removed
```

The issues appears to be the user apache is getting bounced by Postfix, ideally I would like Postfix to send anyway for this user.

Postfix config

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost.$mydomain
mydomain = example.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

Comment: Added log, as mentioned it is being routed internally to the "root" mail box

Comment: Your log shows a successful delivery. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Please list detailed which mails are delivered to which host and what you want. You neither state the current and expected behavior of your server nor do you provide concrete configurations, or a description of your setup (i.e. correct host and domain names).

Comment: As I have mentioned the problem only occurs when sending mail to the domain of the host, i.e those mails are routed internally to the "root" users mail folder. All other e-mails to other domains are sent correctly i.e externally.

Comment: What is the system's hostname?

Comment: Is PHP on this machine configured to send via the local postfix instance or directly?

Comment: It's using Postfix because when I change main.cf it affects PHP being able to send at all, or not.

Comment: The hostname would be test.com in this example

Comment: Post the entire maillog after you invoke `mail` with **and** without `-r` parameter. Above maillog is only partial mail.log. You need to post all related maillog, for example `grep 97E7425671A mail.log`

Comment: Ok I have cleared the mail log run the two test and posted above.

Comment: From the log I can see it is bouncing because apache@test.com does not exist. I have added that and this solves the problem but is there a setting in Postfix I can add so that apache@test.com doesn't need to be created?

Comment: Added to post, too long for here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to remove one of MTA. Having two MTAs in one system can yield unexpected result. *Because I only have experience with postfix, then I suggest you to [remove sendmail](https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/postfix#head-0a5cbfe5357c64b698ecfea3aae71746dbe34d9f)*. With this removal, `mail` command will use postfix instead sendmail as default agent.

```
yum remove sendmail
```

Second, you can set [default sendmail parameter in php.ini](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2012/04/change-default-from-email-name-from-www-data/) with [`sendmail_path`](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php#ini.sendmail-path)  parameter for example

```
sendmail_path = '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f test@example.com'
```

PS: according to [this man page](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html), `-r` flag is obsolete form of the `-f` flag. So, I prefer to use `-f`.

Third regarding [your comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/691976/centos-6-postfix-wont-send-to-own-domain-without-flag/692069#comment853163_691976):

*From the log I can see it is bouncing because apache@example.com does not exist. I have added that and this solves the problem but is there a setting in Postfix I can add so that apache@example.com doesn't need to be created?*

This error message

> 550-Verification failed for  550-No Such User Here" 550 Sender verify failed

wasn't thrown by postfix. The email has been rejected by your actual mail server `mail.**z*.net` which running **Exim**. You need to talk to the Exim administrator why it behaves like that

Answer (score 1):

In your `main.cf` is a parameter called `mydestination`. Remove the domain name form there, so mails to the domain won't be delivered locally no longer.

Before:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, $mydomain
```

After:

```
mydestination = $myhostname
```

`$myhostname` should remain in this list for the internal mails (cron, apt, error messages, etc.)

Comment: I still don't understand the connection between `mydestination` and flag `-r` in mail command. Anyway, based on his mail.log, I believe that his problem can be solved by this answer

Comment: `-r` sets the from address, see the manpage of `mail`.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Flag `-r` only affected the **sender** address, but based the mail.log (and your solution) the problem is `mydestination`. AFAIK there are no correlation between sender address and `mydestination` parameter.

Comment: I have just tried that and quite a lot of other combinations for mydestination but it is not fixing the problem.